# Viewing a-frame with Lenovo headset that uses Microsoft Windows Mixed Reality

Tags: aframe, mixed

I got a Lenovo headset that uses Microsoft Windows Mixed Reality.
I cannot figure out how to use it to see 360 degree a-frame webpages.
When I click the VR glasses on the right lower corner nothing happens.
When I use the MR portal, I can only see the page in a plane, not the whole 360.
Does the html of the a-frame need to have some special activation for Windows MR?
I can see them with another headset using Google Cardboard.

Answer (score 0):

Windows MR headsets are only supported directly by Microsoft Edge and indirectly by Firefox and [Supermedium](https://store.steampowered.com/app/803010/Supermedium__Virtual_Reality_Browser/) through SteamVR (You need to install [this application](https://store.steampowered.com/app/719950/Windows_Mixed_Reality_for_SteamVR/))